# Problemas usando getKeyCode()

Tags: java, eventos

Estoy empezando a programar eventos en java y tengo un problema con getKeyCode().
En un JFrame de mi programa agregué `this.addKeyListener(lamina1);` (lamina1 es una instancia de una clase que hereda de JPanel)
este es el código del listener:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        chars.add(numcaracteres, true);
    }else{
        char txt=e.getKeyChar();
        chars.add(numcaracteres, txt);
    }

    numcaracteres++;

    repaint();

}
```

(chars es una instancia de ArrayList)
El problema que tengo es que `if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)` no funciona, porque cuando presiono enter, no ejecuta el código dentro del if, intenté cambiar `VK_ENTER` por otros valores para comprobar si era solo con enter, pero pasa lo mismo con cualquier otro valor

Comment: No deberias usar KeyListeners, sino KeyBindings. Leete este tutorial (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa [KeyBindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) . KeyListener tiene 2 grandes deficiencias.

- a) Escuchas todas las keys
- b) Tienes que tener foco en el componente y ademas dicho componente tiene que ser focusable.

En cambio con KeyBindings, se bindea por una key y no tienes que estar en foco necesariamente.

Un ejemplo simple:

```
AbstractAction enterAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         //code here example
         ((JComponent)e.getSource()).setVisible(Boolean.FALSE);
    }};
 String key = "ENTER";
 KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);
 component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, key);
 component.getActionMap().put(key, enterAction);
```

Puedes usar estas constantes de JComponent

```
WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT 
WHEN_FOCUSED 
WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW
```